# Error while running emulator on visual studio code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have installed visual studio code successfully and have installed emulator successfully but when i want to run my project i get this error :

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:50407/d2ExRenppQ0=/ws
Exited (sigterm)
```

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRoA5.png) | [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j19F8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could be your API version as indicated here or if you are behind a proxy - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19056

Comment: i could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently an issue running Flutter with android Q. Try using an emulator with android 28 (Pie) instead of android 29 (Q).

Other workarounds that might help can be found here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32651